# How do I require Two Factor Authentication to log in?

Tags: login, security, ecryptfs

Running 12.04. I am trying to separate my wrapped-passphrase for my encrypted home folder to require a USB drive be present to login.

I followed the instructions [here](http://blog.dustinkirkland.com/2009/03/ubuntu-encrypted-home-with-2-factor.html) and added the drive to my fstab, put the wrapped-passphrase file on the drive, and then created a symbolic link back to `~/.ecryptfs`. The drive mounts fine but the symbolic link doesn't seem to be connecting the two as when I login it flashes a purple screen for a fraction of a second than takes me back to the login screen. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you run `ls -l /home/youruser/.ecryptfs`

Comment: In addition to the above, please also do `tail /var/log/syslog` immediately after such a failed login attempt and post the output. This will contain any ecryptfs errors.

Answer (score 1):

[This thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=992426) details how to use a USB stick as your boot device, though for different reasons. I like the fact that without the stick the machine appears to have no OS on it.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score -1):

Have you considered this: "[How to Secure SSH with Google Authenticator’s Two-Factor Authentication](http://www.howtogeek.com/121650/how-to-secure-ssh-with-google-authenticators-two-factor-authentication/)"?

Its not a USB it is an app on our phone that generates a code.

Comment: I dont think he is talking about google authentication

Comment: I get that hes not talking about Google auth. (I read the post) I mentioned it because it is a two factor system, and it seems that the purpose of OP's link was to secure the hard drive with 2 factor.     The google auth system is a "something you have" this it is somewhat relevant. i would have left that link as a comment, but I lacked the rep at the time.