# Log in to Ubuntu with 2 factor

Tags: 14.10, yubikey

I recently purchased a Yubikey and I would like to use it to log into my computer. A quick Google search turned up nothing obviously useful to me. I am running Ubuntu 14.10; does anyone know of a way to do this?

I did look at the suggested post (the list that appears before a question is submitted) and I found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/232960/how-do-i-require-two-factor-authentication-to-log-in) but I don't think it's trying to do the same thing. I think what this post is saying is that upon booting the pc the encryption passphrase is asked for, and the OP would like multi-factor for that. If this is incorrect someone please correct me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the `libpam-yubico` package. You can find details on configuring in the [README](https://github.com/Yubico/yubico-pam/blob/master/README) from the upstream repository. The documentation should also be installed along with the package.

Comment: I can see that package isn't in my current set of repos. As a side question how to I figure out the name of a repo to add? Is there a standard way of knowing? What's the name of this one?

Comment: got it: sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yubico/stable

Comment: Sorry, I transposed the parts of the package name. It's `libpam-yubico` actually.

Comment: I figured it out from the README you linked to